# In electron 4.0.1 how do you hide the menu bar under linux

Tags: electron

In electron 1.8.7 I could just do this:

```
.on('browser-window-created', (e, window) => {
    window.setMenu(null);
})
```

But in electron 4.0.1 this doesn't seem to work anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should work the same way, but looks like there's a bug in Electron (https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/15901). <s>A workaround is suggested in the comments: Set `autoHideMenuBar`-option to true when creating the BrowserWindow-object. Unfortunately that will still show the menu when alt key is pressed.</s>

Edit: There's a better workaround. Use [`BrowserWindow.setMenuBarVisibility(false)`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winsetmenubarvisibilityvisible-windows-linux).

Alternatively, you can try Electron version 3.